# Undefined offset: 1 when checking if isset in function

Tags: php, isset

```
$s = "text";
$exploded_s = explode('/', $s);
//$s2 = isset_or($exploded_s[1], "empty"); //This shows notice Undefined offset: 1
$s2 = isset($exploded_s[1]) ? $exploded_s[1] : "empty"; //This is ok
echo $s2;

function isset_or($var, $val){
    return isset($var) ? $var : $val;
}
```

Both return "empty" but the first way also shows the notice. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `$var` by value - because it has none (and isn't set) you get the notice. However, if you [pass by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) it will work.

```
function isset_or(&$var, $val){
    return isset($var) ? $var : $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$exploded_s[1]` is evaluated to pass the value to `isset_or` as your function specifies to pass the parameter by value.

When using `isset`, the value of `$exploded_s[1]` will not be evaluated, as it is passed by reference; essentially passing the memory address where the value of the second element on the array would be stored if it were not undefined.

Further information here: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)